# Trying Foreman Start and get this long error. What gives?

Tags: ruby, django, python-2.7, heroku

This is what is happening, I'm a newb so if someone could explain what this means and how to fix it it be greatly appreciated. Trying to launch a Django project using Heroku.  After typing Foreman Start in terminal this is the error I recieve:

```
(coffeedapp2)Uzers-MBP-3:coffeedapp uzer-y$ foreman start
/Users/uzer-y/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/psych-2.0.13/lib/psych.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14] 
-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
  See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
 * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
 * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
 * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
 * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   the more detail of.
-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0014 p:-17578513380292 s:0070 e:000069 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0013 p:---- s:0068 e:000067 CFUNC  :require
c:0012 p:0115 s:0064 e:000063 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0011 p:0007 s:0054 e:000053 TOP    /Users/uzer-y/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/psych-2.0.13/lib/psych.rb:1 [FINISH]
c:0010 p:---- s:0052 e:000051 CFUNC  :require
c:0009 p:0115 s:0048 e:000047 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0008 p:0009 s:0038 e:000037 TOP    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/yaml.rb:5 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:---- s:0036 e:000035 CFUNC  :require
c:0006 p:0115 s:0032 e:000031 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0005 p:0063 s:0022 e:000021 TOP    /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/cli.rb:8 [FINISH]
c:0004 p:---- s:0020 e:000019 CFUNC  :require
c:0003 p:0115 s:0016 e:000015 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0002 p:0090 s:0006 E:0010b8 EVAL   /usr/bin/foreman:13 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:0010a8 TOP    [FINISH]
/usr/bin/foreman:13:in `<main>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

/usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/cli.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/yaml.rb:5:in`'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
/Users/uzer-y/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/psych-2.0.13/lib/psych.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------
* Loaded script: /usr/bin/foreman
* Loaded features:

0 enumerator.so

```
1 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/enc/encdb.bundle

2 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/enc/trans/transdb.bundle

3 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/rbconfig.rb

4 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb

5 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb

6 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb

7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb

8 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb

9 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb

10 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/platform.rb

11 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb

12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb

13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb

14 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/thread.rb

15 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb

16 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb

17 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb

18 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/pathname.bundle

19 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb

20 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/version.rb

21 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman.rb

22 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/helpers.rb

23 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/shellwords.rb

24 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb

25 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/procfile.rb

26 /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/dotenv-0.11.1/lib/dotenv/substitutions/variable.rb

27 /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/dotenv-0.11.1/lib/dotenv/substitutions/command.rb

28 /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/dotenv-0.11.1/lib/dotenv/parser.rb

29 /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/dotenv-0.11.1/lib/dotenv/environment.rb

30 /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/dotenv-0.11.1/lib/dotenv.rb

31 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/delegate.rb

32 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/etc.bundle

33 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb

34 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tmpdir.rb

35 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tempfile.rb

36 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb

37 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine.rb

38 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine/cli.rb

39 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/ostruct.rb

40 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/base.rb

41 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/inittab.rb

42 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/util.rb

43 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/strscan.bundle

44 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/erb.rb

45 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/upstart.rb

46 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/daemon.rb

47 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/bluepill.rb

48 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/runit.rb

49 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/supervisord.rb

50 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/launchd.rb

51 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/systemd.rb

52 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export.rb

53 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb

54 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby /2.0.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
 [NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: There isn't enough information for us to answer this question. It might be a bug in `foreman` or a mistake on your end.

Comment: What info do you need maybe I can provide it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a mismatch in Ruby versions -- your gemset is using Ruby 2.2, but Foreman is looking for 2.0.  The way I resolved the issue is to run

```
gem install foreman
```

for the gemset I am using.  Then `foreman start` will reference the local (instead of global) instance of `foreman`.

Answer (score 0):

If all gems are already installed `bundle install`.. try to run executing `bundle exec foreman start`